# Javascript: Advise on variable creation

Tags: javascript

I have a couple of questions with regards to JS.

When ever I need to return something from a function then I normally create a variable and then return the variable, this it seems maybe bad practise as I am creating a variable first and then returning the value and I could just return the value. Is this true ? Reason behind this ?

Variable creation at top of function OR only create a variable when its needed ?

I have been creating all variables at the top of the function, would it be beneficial to only create variables when I need to use them ? I am using ES 2015 and also other places ES5.

And the last thing I would like to check is the creation of variables on one line or separate lines i.e.

```
   var myFirstVariable = 1;
   var mySecondVariable = 2;
   var myThirdVariable = 3;
```

vs

```
   var myFirstVariable = 1,
       mySecondVariable = 2,
       myThirdVariable = 3;
```

Does either style cause issues?

Comment: The first and third question boil down to taste — if one style is more readable than the other, use that. The second one doesn’t really matter as variable declarations are hoisted anyway. You could put all the `var` declarations at the top of the function and define them later.

Comment: All of this is purely based on personal preference. Some consider things unnecessarily wordly, others like to spell them out.

Comment: Another thing: don’t ask three questions in one post. Ask one question per post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When ever I need to return something from a function then I normally
>   create a variable and then return the variable, this it seems maybe
>   bad practise as I am creating a variable first and then returning the
>   value and I could just return the value. Is this true ? Reason behind
>   this ?

This is mainly a coding style thing.  If there is no other use for the variable, then you can just directly return the value without first assigning it to a local variable as there is really no reason to first assign it to a local variable.  If that value is being used for other things before being returned, then you would likely want to assign it to a local variable to avoid computing it more than once.

For example, in this:

```
function multiply(x, y) {
    var val = x * y;
    return val;
}
```

There's really no reason for the `val` variable.  You can just as easily do:

```
function multiply(x, y) {
    return x * y;
}
```

Today's interpreters are probably smart enough to recognize local variables that have no other use other than a return value and optimize them out, but most people would suggest that you should avoid using extra lines of code that are not needed and serve no other purpose.

> Variable creation at top of function OR only create a variable when
>   its needed ?

Again, this is a coding style choice.  All `var` declarations in Javascript are hoisted to the top of the function scope so it does not technically matter whether they are declared first at the top of the scope vs. inline later in the function.  There are legitimate situations for both with regards to maximum code readability.

`let` declarations are hoisted to the top of the containing block so there is a difference with a `let` declaration whether it is declared within a block or at the top of the function, but no difference if it is declared within a block or at the top of the block.

> And the last thing I would like to check is the creation of variables
>   on one line or separate lines

Your second option:

```
var myFirstVariable = 1,
    mySecondVariable = 2,
    myThirdVariable = 3;
```

is simply less typing, but is functionally no different than your first option.  Most people prefer using commas to separate multiple, consecutive declarations, but this is again just a coding style choice to minimize typing as there is no functional difference.

Comment: Also `let` (since user tagged as `es6`)

Comment: @zerkms - Added notes about `let` too.

Comment: Manually putting `let` variables at the top makes no sense imo. `let` and `const` variables should be declared where they are initialised. The TDZ was invented to counter exactly the problem that led to the "declare everything at top" style, there's no reason to use it any more in ES6.

Comment: Regarding variable declaration lists, spelling them out can make code maintenance (moving statements around) easier. There's always a second side of the coin (although I prefer conciseness myself) :-)